# Writing a number guesser that finds values through factors. Trying to check after each factor is found

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

I'm writing a guessing agent for a random number generator. What I currently have written is

```
public int guessStrategy() {
       if (primes.isEmpty()
`// what should happen here is I check 
//if discovered has increased in size since the last time guessStrategy is //run`)
 {
                    int guess = 1;
                    for (Term t : discovered) {
                        guess *= (int) Math.pow(t.base, t.exp);
                    }
                    return guess;
               } else {
                    int guess = primes.pop();
                    myCurrentGuess = guess;
                    return guess;
                }
            }
```

What this does is guess every prime number between 0 and 100 which is located in a list (primes). The world tells the agent if it is a factor and how many times it goes into the random number, that information is in discovered and is part of the term class.

What I want to do is instead of guessing when the list of primes is empty, I want to do what is in the "if(primes.isEmpty())" every time something is added to discovered. The world automatically adds the term to discovered if it is correct.

In other words, I want to test if the latest guess was added as a term to discovered, then run what's in the if statement, and if that guess isn't correct, return to the

```
    } else {
        int guess = primes.pop();
        myCurrentGuess = guess;
        return guess;
    }
}
```

and keep going. What I think needs to be done is check if the length of discovered has increased, yet I'm not sure how to do that without the program getting stuck.

Comment: Unfortunately it's quite unclear to me what you are asking. I *think* you're asking how to detect if a list has changed size but that's just a guess. Could you perhaps show what the finished solution should look like in pseudocode and highlight the section you're struggling with?

Comment: Yes, I need to detect if the size of list discovered has increased, however the location it increases is not in this code. What I think I need to do is set a variable to the size of discovered and check if the size has increased and if it has, change the size of discovered to that. However where it falls apart is in declaration as declaring a variable to be the size of discovered resets each time ProvidePlay is called (I think), which it is during each guess.

Comment: Can you make it a class variable? Then it's value won't change with each invocation.

Comment: If I make it a class variable, then how would I check if the size has increased? Yes, I can make it a class variable.

Comment: Kind of hard to follow your logic, but if you want to track changes you either need to tap into the setting of new values, or have a flag somewhere. Or possibly the solution could be to do all inserts into a new temporary lists, and at the point where you need to know if it has changed you move all temporary items, if any, into the real list. That is a fool proof way of handling it.